# How to update a Stepper value from another function in Swift

Tags: swift

How do I update the "intensityStepper" stepper value to 0 from the "firstSignal" button function?

```
@IBAction func intensityStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
//code
}

 @IBAction func firstSignal(_ sender: Any) {
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the outlet to your controller and not only the IBAction (select outlet and not action from the dropdown after you control drag). This way you can access the stepped from the other function.

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering what the code looks like in the firstSignal Function I have for the other button?

Comment: After you connect it, let say you call it myStepper. You can set it using: myStepper.value = 1

Comment: No problem. If it solved the problem would be great if you marked it as correct and upvoted it =)